# Can I map a subdirectory to an IP or domain?

Tags: .htaccess, web, dns

Is it possible to display the contents of a website domain to a subdirectory using .htaccess or the DNS zone file?

For example, I need to display the contents of 123.123.123.123 at mydomain.com/blog. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to create a DNS A record blog.example.com pointing to the IP Address, then have a HTTP redirect to send it to the subdirectory.

You would need to create a virtual host on your server to host the file for the redirect

Comment: Thanks! (2 years later)